# Direct Engineering from UML Diagrams

Tags: c#, uml

I can't find any resource (book, blog, etc.) that explains how to produce C# code from UML Diagrams, manually.

I find ways to do it automatically using VS, or other UML Products, but now I'm interested in how to do it manually.

I only found a blog that explained how to produce code from some relationships like association, dependencies, etc.

Thanks in advance,

Rafael

Comment: What do you mean by "manually"? Write some code corresponding to the uml diagram? Also which uml diagrams are you talking about?

Comment: For example, suppose you have a class diagram, it tells you what class type you have to create in C#, along with its attributes and methods, inheritances, etc.. Are there some rules to follow along with the whole story, I mean, you build the diagrams and then you have to code what you described in diagrams.

Comment: I don't see the problem... C# is object oriented, so you can do whatever your uml diagram describes (except polymorphism), do you have a question about the object oriented capabilities of C#? Or something about a particular syntax?

Comment: What I need is some kind of guidelines, there are always many ways to code somehing, bur there should be some guidelines. I guess that the developers of the popular uml tools know these guidelines to create a code generator from UML diagrams. Having good guidelines always lead you through the path of the best practices

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you're over-thinking this. UML **class** diagrams can be directly translated to code, that's why there are software that can generate some code from it.

And there is only one way to do it. Your diagram can't be "translated" to code in different ways.

If you have an inheritance, then you'll have inheritance in your code, if your class has an association, there will be a property holding that association in your code.

You can either write some code corresponding to the diagram or some code that doesn't, it's as simple as that.

You just have to follow what you have defined in your diagram

Comment: Ok, that's for the Class Diagram, but what about the other diagrams, Use case, object, there should be some kind of best practices, if I'm in front of a class diagram, there are many ways I can code an association, or dependency. There must be some sort of guideline, best practices, something...

Comment: I don't see how you can code differently an association or dependency... If you do so, it means you don't follow what is in your diagram. If I put it in another way, there will be only 1 possible class diagram based on the code if you reverse engineer it. Anyway, design patterns are used during conception, it means while you're designing your class diagram. For other diagrams, they will lead to the class or sequence diagram, you can't just code them without having those 2 (or at least having an idea of how you want things to work)

Comment: I think I found something. I don't know why you say that we don't need anything, there's a big difference in doing something out of one's wit and guidelines aimed to follow best practices. This is what I found (http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/rsahelp/v8/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.xtools.transform.uml2.cs.doc%2Ftopics%2Fcucstransf.html) but I still think there must be something else

Comment: Ok I looked at your link, and this is only useful if you don't know the language in which you want to make the code for your uml diagram... If you do know C# you don't need this, it's just common sens

Comment: No, it explicitly says: UML-to-C# transformations description, it's not java or other...

Comment: You misunderstood me, I meant that this link might be useful if you're not used to C# and/or don't have much OOP knowledge. If you are used to C# and have OOP knowledge, what is described in this article is common sens, things that every developer (who also knows UML) should have already known